# down towards the old train tracks

Tags: meaning-in-context, word-meaning

The following is the opening paragraph to *The Girl on the Train*:

> She’s buried beneath a silver birch tree, **down** towards the old train tracks, her grave marked with a cairn.

Is the word **down** necessary? What is its semantic contribution?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's telling us that the train tracks are "down" from the "here" of the narrator.  Perhaps the downhill side of town, perhaps the old train tracks are in a railway cutting.  It's giving us a sense of the physical geography and simultaneously giving us an emotional clue.  It's not **over** towards the old train tracks: somewhere away from here, suggesting a distance.  It's not **up** towards the tracks, suggesting effort to get there.  It's **down** towards the old train tracks, a place you might fall to.

Comment: So it means "in a downward direction"?

Comment: Yes, it has just its ordinary meaning, which in a town can mean "down the road" or "downhill".